# Passing information using AJAX post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a module list which retrieves all the modules available from the database. Each module listed will consist a "subscribe" button. When user click the button without logging in at the first place, a login pop up will be shown which asks him/her to log in before subscribing to the module.

What I need to achieve here is to send the input from users to the server, verify the user and log him in. However I am having a problem where the user input ***does not get passed to the right php file in the server***.

**module.php:**

```
    <div id="login-form" title="Sign In"> 
                        <p class="validateTips">Please sign in to continue.</p>
                        <form>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                            <button id="login-button">Login</button>
                        </fieldset>
                        </form>
    </div>
```

**module.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#login-button").click(function() {   
        var post_username = $("#username").val();
        var post_password = $("#password").val();
        $.post("validate.php", {
            username: post_username, 
            password: post_password
        });     
    });


    $("#login-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {

            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }   
    });


    $(".subscribe").click(function() {  
        $("#login-form").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

**validate.php:**

```
  $username = $_REQUEST["username"];
  $password = $_REQUEST["password"];

  // php verification code goes here…
```

Now the problem is the user input ***are not getting passed to validate.php***. Instead, the inputs are appended at the end of the **module.php**. I guess the problem was due to AJAX post but unfortunately I still can't figure it out. Anyone can shed some lights here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your AJAX request to go to `validate.php`, then that's the url you have to use in the `$.post` call

```
$.post("validate.php", {
    username: post_username, 
    password: post_password
});
```

After your edit...

In your PHP file, the values are not going to be in `$_REQUEST`, but in the `$_POST` array. For example:

```
$_POST['username']
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake there in my question. I did specify the correct filename but the input still get passed on the same page which is module.php.